# 'error=''unicode' object has no attribute 'items''

Tags: android, rest, retrofit2

I am making a POST request using Retrofit, call executes successfully on rest client. Also `onResponse` of call executes but in response body i am getting error

> 'unicode' object has no attribute 'items'.

What is the reason of this error?

Comment: your object is a String, so it doesn't have `items` attribute

Comment: This is something new to me, how should i add it or resolve this thing?